# CSS image placement way off depending on screen resolution

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, resolution

If you navigate to http://magee.darkslidedesign.com you will see images on the main page in jQuery Slides. On either side of the slide, there is a "previous" and "next" button.

I have these images placed in a certain location in the following CSS...

```
#slides .next,#slides .prev {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: -215px;
    width:24px;
    height:43px;
    display:block;
    border: 0;
}

#slides .next {
    margin-left: 827px;
}
```

I need some help trying to figure out the best way to have these arrows stay at the same spot they are in 1600x900 resolution if a person has lower or higher resolution.

Help?

Comment: PS: When you rollover the menu links, then the element isn't loading fast enough and displays white background. You can fix that by putting those images inside a sprite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm... the layout is kinda funky... one thing you can do is remove `margin-left: 100px;` on `.prev`, remove the `margin-left: 827px` on `.next`, add `right:0px;` to `.next`, and lastly add `position:relative` to the 60% wide container that holds the slides div.  You may also want to put a `min-width: 750px;` to that same 60% wide div.

if you always want them to stay in the same spot, give the 60% wide div a fixed width of 800px or so (`width:800px`).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "layout is kinda funky" or how that was relevant... but your recommendation worked, I was just trying to get away from fixed width upon initial creation. Thanks.

Comment: @Rory and you did a good job of it.  It scales itself well (with the one exception that the center needs to be fixed because of it's image content).  The reason why I said it was funky was because it used margins to align things.  This is not a patently *bad* way of doing things, it's just not typical.  (Adobe's new Muse program uses a similar method with padding for instance). In any case, Sorry for my wording. I didn't mean to knock it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
#slides {
    position:relative;
}

#slides .next,#slides .prev {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px; // use this instead of margins, of course change the value
    left: -30px // Try with this
    width:24px;
    height:43px;
    display:block;
    border: 0;
}

#slides .next {
    right: -30px; // Change the value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to fix this as the html code is not valid as a first thing. Also, having position absolute on your arrows is not a wise thing to do, as it starts to very dependent of the header..while it should be depending on only the slider itself. It appears that when you change the position: absolute; inside `#slides .next,#slides .prev`, then the the slider stops working correctly. It almost feels, like the slider is being put wherever `.prev` sits. So the .prev is like a placeholder.

Based on those reasons, I strongly believe, that you cannot fix this problem from CSS point of view only. I recommend to optimize your HTML, make it valid. And possible use a different slider. Because, usually placing the arrows outside the slider looks something like this:

```
<style>
#hero_wrapper {float: left; border: 1px dotted blue; padding: 0px 60px;}
    #hero_images {border: 1px dotted red; width: 500px; height: 300px;}
    #hero_prev,
    #hero_next {position: relative; margin-top: 110px; padding: 20px; font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold; border: 1px dotted green; /* #hreo_next special: */ float: left; margin-left: -60px;}
    #hero_next {float: right; margin-right: -60px;}
</style>
<div id="hero_wrapper">
    <div id="hero_prev">&lt;</div>
    <div id="hero_next">&gt;</div>
    <div id="hero_images"></div>
</div>
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/BEWMp/) ]**</sup>

I'm sorry that I cannot give you concrete answers, but I hope that when you understand how easy the basic concept is.. you will reconsider using that slider (as I'm assuming that the sliders DOM structure is not optimal.) Also, technically you simply find a slider that has stand-alone arrows (I personally like [the jQuery Orbit Plugin](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider)) and simply use my basic concept of the slider structure. Because, in that case you only need to make the `#hero_images` slide and hook the prev and next functions to the arrows, and voila!

Some pointers:

- As I mentioned in the comment above, your menu images should be in a sprite, so the white background wouldn't get displayed on rollover.
- Meta tags should be ended with `/` in xhtml.
- Also google analytics strongly recommends to put their code before `</body>` in the footer.
- In modern website development nobody wants borders for images. And if they do, then they will set it manually anyways (`.someimg {border: 1px solid black;}`). So to [avoid non-valid xhtml](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=56282), then add predefined img value on the top of your css: `img {border: 0px;}`
- Also you got some other non-standard attributes. [Use a validator!](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://magee.darkslidedesign.com/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)
- Normally in a slider the images are put inside a `ul` list..

Comment: This is what I was thinking but not as elaborate. +1

Comment: I fixed it via CSS. The prev and next buttons work just fine, and always have. I'm not sure what part of my HTML is invalid, but, it's structured fine and also works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Validator says: 20 Errors, 2 warning(s). Its invalid. As what goes for "fixed", it is the same in IE7 and IE6. While IE6 is really outdated, then IE7 is still being used and is a valid benchmark. As a totally personal note I wouldn't defend that code as @Roy said, its funky. And really, don't be offended, but if you would work for me and say that, that codes structure is fine -- I would fire you. Take this as, if you would research a little on better methods you could ask for money from your clients.

Comment: Dude the problems are img tags not being closed - that has nothing to do with the structure of the HTML being bad nor does it make troubleshooting the problem any more or less difficult. The problem was I wasn't using fixed widths, and I changed it as such, and it's working fine. Stop being pretentious and get off your high horse, man.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting my point. I do know the feeling, when somebody is being picky about your code.. but if you would look past it and make effort to make it better, then you can only gain from it. img-tag being closed does mean invalid code, if it works that's good. But there are issues related to non-standard code. I'm sorry if you took this in negative context, but the point is that you got some growth-room with browser-compatibility and web 2.0 standards.